# bash script creates multiple process & cannot close by ctrl-c

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script which executes multiple python scripts.
For example:

```
python pyscript.py &> log1
python pyscript2.py &> log2
```

while executing this script, I found a few error in python script.
So I tried to kill process simply by ctrl-c, which did not work.

When I looked up at process by `ps -ef pyscript*`, this single bash file made multiple process at once, which I did not expected it to be.

eventually I killed all processes by hand, but it was not a clean way to do.
Is there a reason that this bash script makes multiple process?

thanks in advance

Comment: You ran it with `sh` instead of bash. `&>` is only special in bash, so in `sh` it acts like `& >`, first creating a background process, and then (separately) creating an empty file (without redirecting the process's output to the file).

Comment: what does your `pyscript.py` do?

Comment: ...really, it's best to avoid `&>` altogether and use `python pyscript.py >log1 2>&1` in the first place. That fixes the unintended backgrounding, and _also_ makes your code compatible with `sh`.

Comment: @GiovanniRescia it runs deep learning process, which takes a lot of time

Comment: try ctrl-z. in some situation ctrl-c doesn't make any interrupt for current process